# Django REST framework returning different http status codes depending on using browser or python's famous Requests library

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am issuing a DELETE request using Django REST framework's RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.
If the object exists, the response code should be 204 "no content".
If I issue a DELETE request again, the response code should be 404.

These are in fact the status codes that I get when using the Chrome extension POSTMAN.  It works! Yes!

Then I go into tests.py and I need to make a unit test, so I figure that python's Requests library is the best thing around.  But I keep getting '200' ok status codes when I run the delete operation, even if I delete the same object 3 times in a row in my unit test.

Is there any reason why the Requests library and the Chrome extension POSTMAN give differing status codes? What am I doing wrong here?

```
        #create a role, then delete it
        #response = self.test_POST_role()
        #print 'response in json of the test_role_POST() is %s : ' % response.json()
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lakeshoreProperties/roles/'
        payload = {
            "name": "test",
            "description": "someone who tests"
        }
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        responseDict = response.json()
        newly_created_role_id = responseDict['id']
        print 'newly created role id is: %s ' % newly_created_role_id

        #delete this newly created role
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lakeshoreProperties/role/' + str(newly_created_role_id)
        print 'going to delete using this url: %s ' % url
        #headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        delete_response = requests.delete(url)
        print 'delete_response text delete is : %s' % delete_response.text
        print 'delete_response code after first delete is is: %d' % delete_response.status_code
#         self.assertEquals(delete_response.status_code, 200)#should be 204 no content, but who knows why???
        #delete again, and get a 404 not found
        delete_response = requests.delete(url) 
        #should be 404 no content b/c you just deleted twice, obj should not be there!
        print 'delete_response code after second delete is: %d' % delete_response.status_code
#         self.assertEquals(delete_response.status_code, 404)
        print 'delete_response code after third delete is: %d' % delete_response.status_code
        self.assertEquals(delete_response.status_code, 404)
```

****all status_codes are 200 inside the above unit test *****

Some logging that is printed in the console when running tests.py is below:

```
.newly created role id is: 59
going to delete using this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/lakeshoreProperties/role/59
delete_response text delete is : {"id": 59, "name": "test", "description": "someone who tests"}
delete_response code after first delete is is: 200
delete_response code after second delete is: 200
delete_response code after third delete is: 200
F.{"id": 60, "name": "test", "description": "someone who tests"}
```

Comment: How is the browser calling the code?